# Visual Studio 2012 will not allow me to create a new project: What to do?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have just installed Visual Studio 2012.  Unfortunately, the "New Project" window has an empty list of project types, and it's impossible for me to properly fill out this window such that the "OK" button is enabled.

Therefore, I cannot create a new project in my fresh installation of VS 2012.

(I'd like to create a native C++ application - a console application would be just fine, to start.)

Here is a screenshot of the "New Project" window in VS 2012.

[image: New Project window in fresh installation of VS 2012]

What should I do?

(I am running Windows 7 64-bit.)

Comment: One thing to do: Reinstall!

Comment: Sounds like an installation problem to me. I would reinstall with all options enabled.

Comment: Reinstall, and this time run the installer as an administrator.

Comment: @KenWhite The installer could not be run in a non-admin account in Win7.

Comment: @MarkGarcia: In what way is that *evident*? There's no indication of how the installer was run; the folder is in the default `C:\Users` directory, which is where a non-admin user's folder would be, and it's entirely possible to launch the installer as a non-admin; it's only automatically elevated if it has certain words (like 'install' or 'setup') in the filename, or is an msi file. (This is frequently what causes folders to be virtualized.)

Comment: @KenWhite There is that yellow and blue shield in the "INSTALL" "clickable" in the installer's UI.

Comment: @Mark: Oh, yeah. There *is* that. :-) Guess I haven't had to run the installer enough to remember.